# Random Not Definied

Tags: python, random

Code -

```
msg = message.content
  
if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter))
```

Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Dank-Village-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 40, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter))
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 291, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: First, fix your formatting. Second, the title has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: Why do you think random isn't defined? That's not what the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `random.choice` on a set unfortunately, you'll have to make a list-ed copy of it to do that

```
starter_list = list(starter)
random.choice(starter_list)
```